# Python, Tkinder, Listbox, how to select 1 item from a listbox?

Tags: python, sqlite, listbox

Well, this should be easy but I just can't find the info I need
I'm a little noob at Python, doing a program with sqlite3 database. Already found how to populate a listbox with my data, but now I need to get data from the 1st item from the selected row...
How do I do this?
I'm using sqlite3, the DB is working, I can add items and see items (populate the listbox), now I need the first item (client number) from that listbox when I click a button, so I can show, in a different frame, the info about that client

```
BD_lista_socios = c.execute("SELECT n_socio, nome, morada_localidade, actividade FROM socio")
dados_socios=BD_lista_socios.fetchall()
for item in dados_socios:
        L_Socios.insert(END,item)
```

Also, can I make the listbox preatyer? IT had no lines, nothing to separate the items

Update: So I can get the index of the item picked, but not the variable in the first objecto of the row.
Used L_Socios.curselection() , so this is giving me the index, but how do I get first item of the row?

Comment: No help? come on... I'm stuck

Comment: Solved:
    BTN_ver_socio = Button(Frame_lista, text=" Ver Sócio ", command= lambda: f_mostra_socio(L_Socios.get(ACTIVE)[0])) ;;

lisbox.get(ACTIVE)[0]) solved it